# How to use new values of attributes?

Tags: jquery

I have one problem. I change attributes

```
$(selector).find('img[data-photoid="' + phid + '"]').attr({"data-value1":"somevalue1", "data-value2":"somevalue2"});
```

I see in DOM on Browser that jQuery changed values. But when I clicked img jQuery uses old values.

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t=$(this);
    var value1=t.data("value1"); //jQuery uses old values
    var value2=t.data("value2"); //although I changed values
});
```

How can I use new values?

Comment: You would still need the `data` prefix since that is what was set. `t.attr("data-value1")`

Comment: Thanks. It works with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to one way of working, not mixing `attr` and `data` methods. The `data` method only takes the attribute value the first time it is referenced, but then lives its own life after that. Quoted from the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-obj):

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. [...] The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

I would suggest changing the code that currently uses `attr`:

```
$(selector).find('img[data-photoid="' + phid + '"]')
           .data("value1", "somevalue1") 
           .data("value2", "somevalue2");
```

You will not see the changes in HTML, but it will run more efficiently.

Comment: Really, I dont see the changes in HTML but it works! Thanks.